# combine multiple criteria into one formulaic results column

Tags: sql, netsuite

I would like to create a formula on the RESULTS tab of saved search that will COUNT Opps when one of multiple criteria exists. Example: count Opportunities that do not have X in Title field, Memo Field or Program field.
I would also like another field to SUM the projected total for these counted Opps
A 3rd results column for % of ALL opps that these above account for.

I've been able to create 3 lines to filter out the Opps I don't want to see but actually need to move these to the results tab into ONE line of formula(numeric) as I'd like to calculate their % of overall opps. Just don't know how to stack the three lines into one results line

```
INSTR({memo}, 'SLII')or
INSTR({title}, 'SLII)or
INSTR({item.custitem_program},'SLII')
```

have not had success building these 3 into one results line

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is a case expression in a formula numeric column:

```
case 
  when INSTR({memo}, 'SLII') > 0 then {amount} 
  when INSTR({title}, 'SLII') > 0 then {amount} 
  when INSTR({item.custitem_program}, 'SLII') > 0 then {amount} 
  else 0 end
```

or for the grouping etc just have an amount column and a formula text column

```
case 
  when INSTR({memo}, 'SLII') > 0 then 'SLII'
  when INSTR({title}, 'SLII') > 0 then 'SLII' 
  when INSTR({item.custitem_program}, 'SLII') > 0 then 'SLII'
  else 'other' end
```

Then you can group on that column and add a second amount column with function "% of total"